# System.String does not overload operator += But String Concatenation works, How?

Tags: c#, .net, string, compiler-construction, clr

The System.String has only two Operator overloaded

```
public static bool operator ==(string a, string b)
{
  return string.Equals(a, b);
}

public static bool operator !=(string a, string b)
{
  return !string.Equals(a, b);
}
```

But when using += for String concat, Example :

```
    private static void Main()
    {
        String str = "Hello ";
        str += "World";

        Console.WriteLine(str);
    }
```

it works just fine,

So, how come if System.String doesn't overload the operator += it Concats the string?

Comment: Int doesn't overload addition either. So how can you add numbers?

Comment: @EricLippert - never checked the Int32 in reflector, this question was just for curiosity

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First, the operator `+=` can't be overloaded. If you have the expression `A += B`, it's compiled as if you wrote:*

```
A = A + B
```

Okay, that's why `string` doesn't overload `operator +=` (because it can't be overloaded). So, why doesn't it overload `operator +` either? It's just one more difference between the CLR and C#. The C# compiler knows that types like `string` and `int` are special, and it generates special code for their operators (calling `string.Concat()` for `string`, or the `add` instruction for `int`).

Why are these operators treated in a special way? Because you want them treated in a special way. I think this is most clear for `int`:

1. You don't want each `int` addition to be compiled as a method call, that would add a lot of overhead. Because of that, special instruction for `int` addition is used.
2. Integer addition doesn't always behave the same with regards to overflows. There is a compiler switch to throw exceptions for overflows and you can also use the `checked` and `unchecked` operators. How should the compiler deal with that if it had only `operator +`? (What it actually does is to use the instruction `add` for unchecked overflows and `add.ovf` for checked overflows.)

And you want to treat `string` addition in a special way too, for performance reasons. For example, if you have `string`s `a`, `b` and `c` and write `a + b + c` and then you compiled that as two calls to `operator +`, you would need to allocate a temporary `string` for the result of `a + b`, which is inefficient. Instead, the compiler generates that code as `string.Concat(a, b, c)`, which can directly allocate only one string of the required length.

---

* This is not exactly right, for details, see Eric Lippert's article [*Compound Assignment, Part One*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/03/29/compound-assignment-part-one.aspx) and [*Compound assignment*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#compound-assignment) in the C# specification. Also note the missing semicolons, `A += B` really is an expression, for example, you can write `X += Y += Z;`.

Answer (score 5):

There is no overload of `+=` operator, its a **short-hand** for `var = var + newValue`. Same is the case with strings.

[+= Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa7629ew.aspx)

> The += operator cannot be overloaded directly, but user-defined types
>   can overload the + operator

Consider the following example:

```
string str = "new string";
str += "new value";
```

This is equal to :

```
str = str + "new value";
```

which internally calls `string.Concat` at compile time.

Comment: This answer is misleading, and the last sentence is incorrect. The `+` operator [is **not** overloaded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff986396.aspx) on `System.String`; it is replaced *at compile time* with a call to `string.Concat`.

Comment: @codesparkle, I didn't say that + operator is overloaded in strings ??? What I meant was `+=` is short hand for `a = a + b`, for strings. I believe I need to reword my answer

Answer (score 3):

`+=` is not explicitly implemented but it works because compiler do it's magic

```
str += "World";

str =  str + "World";

str = str.Concat("World");
```

Answer (score 0):

As the guys above said, and according to .NET, `string += otherString` is equivalent to

```
string = string + otherString
```

[This .NET link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa7629ew.aspx) mentions the concatenation operator, and [this .NET link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa7629ew.aspx) talks about the relationship between the two operations.